# Netbeans jsp debug

Tags: jsp, netbeans, debugging

How can i see in debug time the value of a el expression?
i.e. ${myBean.myProperty} ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a breakpoint on the getter of `myProperty`- i.e. `getMyProperty()`